# Why is the anchor tag only working on the bottom of the image?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, image

I'm having difficulty turning an image into a clickable link. The image is a chart that's generated by a 3rd party service that we use. The functional image can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3jMdW/ (please note that I've hosted the image on imgur because otherwise you won't be able to see it.)

The problem I'm having is that the link only seems to work along the bottom edge of the image in Firefox. If I click anywhere in the middle of the image, the link doesn't work (even though the hand icon is visible). How can I fix this so that clicking anywhere in the image activates the link request.

Just to note, there is a lot of extra HTML (scripts/tags) associated with the image. This is because the charting service maps a chart to its data points for hover-over info. The client has asked for this specifically so I can't remove it.

Comment: Lots of errors in that fiddle related to missing dependent functions so its difficult to see the behaviour. In some places I see `prop="LEFT"` but in others `prop=LEFT` are `LEFT/CENTER/ABOVE` globals defined elsewhere or are they missing "" ?

Comment: Hi Alex, I copy/pasted all of the HTML returned by the charting service into the jsfiddle. Nothing else is written to the page, so they aren't globals. I'll see if I can modify the template to not include that crap and try to regenerate the links.

Answer (score 0):

Add `href` attributes to your `<area>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the chart template to remove everything that isn't part of the `<img />` tag fixed this.